# Can't find where the debugger statement is on my site - sources panel says VM456

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a Shopify site and often need to use Chrome Developer tools. Recently, for every page load, I keep hitting a debugger statement. It's actually in a setTimeout, so even though I stop it, it keeps coming! I started hitting 'turn off all breakpoints', but that only helps for the current page load.

I exported my entire theme and did a global search, but did not find the line in any of the code.

Here's a screenshot of the sources panel:

[image: Screenshot of debugger statement]

Does anyone have any suggestions? This is getting super frustrating!

Comment: Is there a public link to your shopify site?

Comment: https://lightingoriginals.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the `debugger` statement and select `Never pause here` option.

[image]